# Slide Edge Tool

Tags: modeling, edges, normals, extrude

Hey i wanted to know if blender has a tool or a Mode where i can slide a edge and "move" it up and downwards along its Vertex normals

As Shown here
https://youtu.be/vm2g6GXHD4E?t=383

Also would be interessting to know if you can extrude an Edge depending on its Normals like the "offset" function in Maya

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: xith alt E you have access to the different kind of extrude, and once you've extruded, you can tweak some parameters in the Operator box (bottom left of the 3D view)

Comment: Sadly thats not what i am looking for

for the slide one here is an example from Maya where the Slide tool also can raise and lower the Edge even

https://imgur.com/a/3n5R6yX

The Top one is in Maya where the Middle edge get evenly pushed in or outwards while in Blender using the Scale tool will unevenly push or pull it since edges closer to the Median point will not be effected as much.

Also extruding for Offsetting an Edge is not properly possible 

When you have an Uneven Cylinder and select the boundry edge you can not extrude it evenly it will also be unenven

Comment: You can do it manually but I don't know if there's an automatic way to do it, maybe someone will know

Comment: I will post it on Right Click select and see if someone knows this and if not it definitley should be added since by hand is a bit too unprecise

Comment: Alt-S (Shrink/Fatten) will translate vertices along their vertex-normals, is that it? Not associated with 'sliding' in Blender

Comment: I see! Perfect that seems to be excactly what i needed! Thank you a lot!